# Create bundle id as ITC user

Tags: app-store-connect

My client added me as ITC user but when I'm trying to go to developer.apple.com I got error in safari. So I can't create bundle id for new app as well as manage certs and profiles.

So is it something wrong with my mac or id or it should work like that?
If so, how can I create bundle id and release app to review in this case?

Answer (score 0):

May be you don't have enough rights for that. Say your client to make your role as Technical, so you can create Bundle ID in iTC. For more information about iTC roles, read [here](https://developer.apple.com/support/roles/).